# I am unable to display string data in meteor properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, meteor

I need to display a string from database like "hello world"
where {{{content}}} contains the first 3 characters "hel" and {{{content1}}} contains the rest of the characters.

My html code is

```
<li class="contentMain">{{{content}}}{{{content1}}}</li>
```

CSS code is

```
.contentMain{
    position: relative;
    top: -15px;
    font-family: Palatino Linotype, Georgia, Verdana, sans-serif;
}
```

I want the output to be "hello world".
But it is displaying
"hel
lo world"
Why is there a line break between "hel" and "lo".
Thanking everyone.

Comment: Try using double braces instead of triple. No need to use triple here.
Also, right click the html text in your browser, click inspect element and show us what it says there as the html.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I have solved it by using id instead of class and by making display:inline of paragraph

Answer (score 0):

Use double braces instead as follows:

```
<li class="contentMain">{{content}}{{content1}}</li>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I have solved it by using id instead of class and by making display:inline of paragraph